# Авторизация пользователей PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Есть база в которую я добавляю пользователей.

Код проверки пользователей при входе:

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM  

    users WHERE user_login = :l LIMIT 1");
$result->bindValue(":l", $l, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result->execute();
$res = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
```

Проблема:
Я добавляю пользоватей в базу mysql:

```
Id :1, login:root, pass:root
Id :2, login:admin, pass:admin
```

И так пользователь root войдет без проблем, но пользователь admin даже введя правильные данные войти не может!
При этом если пользователя root удалить то пользователь admin сможет войти!

Тоесть код почему то проверяет только того пользователя у которого id меньше всех (который был создан раньше чем другие).

Проблема в том что скрипт выбирает одного пользователя и только последнего в базе (у которого id наименьшее число). Id пользователя генерируется сам! Все остальные получают ошибку пароля и логина!

Answer (score 1):

Замените `PDO::PARAM_INT` на `PDO::PARAM_STR`.
Очевидно, у вас `user_login` это строковое значение, а параметром `PDO::PARAM_INT` оно приводится к целому числу